# Why is my WebView2 Triggering NavigationStarting Event More Than Once

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, webview2

I have a `WebView2` control in a `WPF` `UserControl`. It is supposed to serve as a normal browser and as a PDF reader. There is a `ComboBox` that changes the state of the `WebView2`. When PDF Reader is selected, the `WebView2` navigates to a blank page ("about:blank") and waits for the User to click a button to load a pdf file from the local file system (Windows 10), and the `WebView2` then navigates to the pdf file using the `WebView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate()` method. Now this is where I am experiencing a strange happening.

If I use the button to load the file, the browser starts navigating and the `WebView2.NavigationStarting` event handler is triggered. But after the navigation is successfully completed, I notice that the `WebView2.NavigationStarting`is triggered again, with the "about:blank" `Uri` instead of the initial pdf file path and the webView presents a blank page.

If I load the pdf file immediately after a `ComboBox` item is selected, however, the pdf file is loaded successfully. Here is the code for `ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged()`:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*if (!WebBrowserMain.ScriptErrorsSuppressed)
    {
        WebBrowserMain.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    }*/
    Office.CustomXMLParts customXMLParts1 = Document.CustomXMLParts;
    Office.CustomXMLParts customXMLParts2 = customXMLParts1.SelectByNamespace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/vsto/samples/buttonsLabel");
    Office.CustomXMLPart customXMLPart = null;
    string selectedItem = ComboDatabaseSelect.SelectedValue.ToString();
    if (customXMLParts2.Count > 0)
    {
        customXMLPart = customXMLParts2[1];
        customXMLPart.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='comboBoxDatabaseSelected']")[1].Text = selectedItem;
    }
    comboBoxSelectedItemBuilder.Clear();
    comboBoxSelectedItemBuilder.Append(ComboDatabaseSelect.SelectedValue.ToString());
    ButtonForward.IsEnabled = true;
    ButtonBack.IsEnabled = true;
    ButtonForward.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ButtonBack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    if (selectedItem.Equals("DOI Search"))
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        HTLMStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Unimats.UI.Resources.HTMLPage.html");
        string HTMLString = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(HTLMStream))
        {
            HTMLString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        WebView2.NavigateToString(HTMLString);
        ButtonReload.Content = "Reset Page";
        ButtonForward.IsEnabled = false;
        ButtonBack.IsEnabled = false;
        ButtonForward.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ButtonBack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else if (selectedItem.Equals("PDF Reader"))
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        HTLMStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Unimats.UI.Resources.PDF_Reader.html");
        string HTMLString = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(HTLMStream))
        {
            HTMLString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        WebView2.Source = new Uri("about:blank", UriKind.Absolute);
        //LoadPDF();
        ButtonReload.Content = "Load PDF";
        ButtonForward.IsEnabled = false;
        ButtonBack.IsEnabled = false;
        ButtonForward.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ButtonBack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        _cancelNavigationToBlank = false;
    }
    else if (selectedItem.Equals("Google Scholar"))
    {
        HTLMStream?.Dispose();

        WebView2.Source = new Uri("https://scholar.google.com", UriKind.Absolute);
        ButtonReload.Content = "Reload";
    }
    else if (selectedItem.Equals("SpringerLink"))
    {
        WebView2.Source = new Uri("https://link.springer.com", UriKind.Absolute);
        ButtonReload.Content = "Reload";
    }
    else if (selectedItem.Equals("ScienceDirect"))
    {
        WebView2.Source = new Uri("https://www.sciencedirect.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
        ButtonReload.Content = "Reload";
    }
    else if (selectedItem.Equals("ResearchGate"))
    {
        WebView2.Source = new Uri("https://www.researchgate.net//search/", UriKind.Absolute);
        ButtonReload.Content = "Reload";
    }
    else if (selectedItem.Equals("ChatGPT"))
    {
        WebView2.Source = new Uri("https://chat.openai.com", UriKind.Absolute);
        ButtonReload.Content = "Reload";
    }
    else if (selectedItem.Equals("Google Bard"))
    {
        WebView2.Source = new Uri("https://bard.google.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
        ButtonReload.Content = "Reload";
    }
    if (customXMLPart != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(customXMLPart);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(customXMLParts2);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(customXMLParts1);
}
```

If I uncomment the `LoadPDF()` method and load the pdf directly from here, everything goes successfully.
This is the method for the button that calls `LoadPDF()` method:

```
private void ButtonReload_Click(object sender, Wins.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadPDF();
}
```

If I load the file using this button, I experience the issue.

This is the `LoadPDF()` method:

```
private void LoadPDF()
{
    OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fileDialog.Title = "Select PDF";
    fileDialog.Filter = "PDF Files(*.pdf) | *.pdf";
    DialogResult resultOk = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (resultOk == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = fileDialog.FileName;
        WebView2?.CoreWebView2?.Navigate(fileName);
    }
}
```

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening please?